# Choose what an array stores based on button press

Tags: java, arrays, swing, data-structures

I'm trying to find a way to pick what an array stores based on which button the user presses on a GUI.

Obviously this will not compile due to the variable name being the same.

The calculations are performed outside of the loop but use "values". I just want the user to be able to determine what values are set in the array based on what button they press. The obvious issue is not being able to use the name "values" twice, which is where I am having a problem as I have a for loop that requires the variable "values" and I don't want to have to be re adding the code several times for each data set when there is most likely an easy workaround that I am currently not seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pull the declaration out:

```
double[] Xvalues = null;
if (e.getSource() == X1btn) {
   Xvalues = new double[]{2001,350,799,1004};
}
else if (e.getSource() == X2btn) {
   Xvalues = new double[]{5,62,28,500};
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Taking the decleration out worked like a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A better approach would be to subclass `JButton` and associate a set of values with each instance. To retrieve the button's values, include an accessor.

### Example

```
public final class JArrayButton extends JButton{
    private final double[] values;

    public JArrayButton(double[] values){
        this.values = values;
    }

    // ... other stuff (e.g. constructors)

    public final double[] getValues(){
        return values;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you create the array ourside the loop.
     double Xvalues[] = new Xvalues[5]; //or whatever size you want

and then use if/else statement

```
if (e.getSource() == X1btn) {
Xvalues ={2001,350,799,1004};
} else if (e.getSource() == X2btn) {
Xvalues={5,62,28,500};
}
```